# other form of uv notation of integration by parts

Tags: integration

So integration by parts looks like this

$\int u\, dv = uv - \int v\, du$

But I have often seen it like this:

$\int uv\,dx = u \int v\, dx - \int (u'\int v dx )\, dx$

I cannot prove this.

$ uv = \int v\, dx$ is trivial

$\int v\, du = \int (u'\int v dx )\, dx$  can be seen by substituting in $du = u'\,dx$

But when it comes to showing $\int u\,dv = \int uv\,dx$ I get stuck.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting tripped up because the $v$ used in each identity is different.  To see why, use each to evaluate $\int x \cos x\,dx$.  In the second identity, $v=\cos x$.  But in the first identity, $dv=\cos x\,dx$, so $v=\sin x$.

Rather, you can prove the second identity by showing that the derivative of the of right-hand side is $uv$.
Since $\left(\int v\,dx\right)' = v$, etc., we have
$$
    \left(u \int v\,dx - \int u' \int v \,dx\right)'
    = u' \int v\,dx + u v - u' \int v\,dx = uv
$$

Answer (score 0):

When I'm treating an integral of the form $\int f(x)\>g(x)\>dx$, indefinite or definite, using partial integration I use the following arrow notation: I put a downward arrow $\downarrow$ under the factor that gets differentiated in the process and an upward arrow $\uparrow$ under the factor that gets integrated. This saves me from introducing new functions $u(x)$ and $v'(x)$ or similar. See the following example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$dv$ is just a mnemonic for $v'dx$ in your first equation, in the second one you are using $v$ in place of $v'$ so $v$ turns into the primitive of $v$, $\int vdx$.